# Only get input Integer

Tags: reactjs

I have this code, where I would like to get only Integers as input, what can I add into it so that it accepts only numbers? 
Thanks in advance

```
 handleChange(event) {
    if (event.target.value === '' || parseInt(event.target.value)) {
      this.props.dispatch({
        type: "SET_INT_INPUT_METHOD",
        payload: event.target.value === '' ? '' : parseInt(event.target.value)
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can define type as number for your input tag.Check out this link https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_number.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dns_nx, doing this check before dispatch, there is no need to run the ternary operator in the payload.

```
handleChange(event) {
    let value = event.target.value
    if(Number.isInteger(value)) {
        this.props.dispatch({
            type: "SET_INT_INPUT_METHOD",
            payload: value
        })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem! Now only integers can be accepted in the field! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, if I got what you mean...

You can check a value if it is numeric with the function `Number.isInteger()`.

Check the documentation:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isinteger.asp

```
 handleChange(event) {
    if (event.target.value === '' || parseInt(event.target.value)) {
        if(Number.isInteger(event.target.value)) {
            this.props.dispatch({
                type: "SET_INT_INPUT_METHOD",
                payload: event.target.value === '' ? '' : parseInt(event.target.value)
            })
        }
        else {
            // do something different
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your input to type number, so it just numbers will be possible to type in:

```
<input type="number">
```